# a href external link to specific area on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

So I have a nav bar that I want to link to different pages that all look the same but have one different section on them. When  I came to creating the links I realized that it will only link to the other page but not the specific section on the page . So basically I had the idea of an anchor tag but linking to another page.

I did it this way because I have a basic knowledge of coding and don't know how to use php and javascript. Is there a way to do this with what I have? Or do I have to try a different method entirely?

I am just learning javascript now so that can be an option. I heard you could do something with arrays? (But not any jquery as we are not allowed to use that for our assignment) I've also heard about iframes also but I don't know too much about them.

CODE:

HTML

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="toursprices.html">TOURS,PRICES &amp; STANDARD FLIGHTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MEET THE STAFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CHARTERS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your page toursprices.html contains a div with id "abc", and you want to link to that section, you just have to write the href like this:

```
<a href="toursprices.html#abc">TOURS,PRICES &amp; STANDARD FLIGHTS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<a id="different_section_1">Different Section</a>
```

in the target page and in the navbar use:

```
<a href="page.html#different_section_1">Page</a>
```

But if your pages are essentially the same with one area that changes. You'd probably be better of using an iframe or switching out blocks with javascript.

Comment: I suppose iframes would be the smarter option but I heard they are quite complicated to work with. I am wondering if it would cause me more problems to use them than just selecting them through an id.

Comment: One of the programming principles is Do Not Repeat Yourself. What you've done now is repeat large blocks of html. That means that if you want to change the text in the repeated block, you'd have to do that for all the blocks. If you're doing this for a homework assignment,  then your solution is probably fine. But if this is code you have to maintain, I'd look into the other options.

Answer (score 0):

As "user3472089" said you can point the a certain element through its id.

I use this at the top of my gallery:

```
<a href="#top"></a>
```

And at the bottom I just put a link or a simulated button that leads to that anchor:

```
<a href="#top">
    <div id="top_anchor">
      UP 
    </div>
</a>
```